# Aggregating string and number columns at the same time using pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

My question is a step further from [this question(Aggregating string columns using pandas GroupBy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357837/aggregating-string-columns-using-pandas-groupby).

From

```
df =

id  type      name        value
1     aa        kk          11
2     bb        mm          22
3     bb        ll          33
4     aa        ll          44
5     bb        kk          55
6     aa        oo          66
7     aa        mm          77
8     bb        ll          88
9     aa        ll          99
```

To

```
id  type    name(list)    value(sum)
1     aa    kk,ll,mm,oo    297
2     bb    kk,ll,mm       198
```

Is this possible? How to achieve this?

Comment: you can aggregate `','.join` and `sum`, for you not working?

Comment: My syntax is ```df.groupby(['type'], as_index=False).agg({'name':','.join, 'value':'sum'})```. But it doesn't work.

Comment: It is good, what menas not working? there is error?

Comment: I see the problem. when I used ```display(df)``` to show the result, the original ```df``` was presented, because I didn't write ```df =``` at the beginning of that sentence.